# Java .set for lists?

Tags: java

I am learning the basics of lists in Java and I was wondering what .set did I already understand the concept of .add however I cant really find anything about .set and its relation to lists other then examples. I would really appreciate if someone could give me some insight on this command.

Comment: If you are going to be a Java programmer, you MUST learn to use the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  Keep them open all the time, and refer to them frequently.  Get used to the way they're laid out and how to navigate between them.  Java is too big to even contemplate programming in, without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set will specify the position in the List for the object you are storing. The List inteface represents an ordered collection of objects so the position is able to be changed. Similar to an array.

Look at the section Positional Access and Search Operators on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: The documentation has this explanation: "*Replaces the element at the specified position* in this list with the specified element"

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful and an extremely helpful link too!

Comment: No problem finding the right Java documentation when you are starting out is difficult. The Oracle Java Tutorials are usually a good starting point :)

Answer (score 2):

`set(pos, elem)` as per the Java docs:

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element.

This means that you can change the stored element/reference at a specific position in the list, as long as the position is within the allowed position bounds. So, if you have 3 elements within the list already, you can specify `position` in `set(position,element)` to a value between 0 and 2, inclusive. Here is a simple demonstration of how you can replace the 1th (so really the 2nd, as it's 0-indexed) element in an ArrayList and then set it back to the original value:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> foo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        foo.add(1);
        foo.add(1);
        foo.add(2);
        foo.add(3);
        System.out.println(foo);
        foo.set(1, 999);
        System.out.println(foo);
        foo.set(1, 1);
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

But really, this is explained more than clearly enough in the Java doc for `List`, so as others have said: read it and try it out next time.